# What is the way to serialize a user-defined class?

Tags: django, serialization

What should a user-defined class implements if I want to serialize it? For my case, I want to serialize a list named

```
comment_with_vote = []
```

elements of which are objects defined as follows.

```
class CommentWithVote(object):
    def __init__(self, comment, vote):
        self.comment = comment
        self.vote = vote # vote=1 is_up,vote=0 is_down,vote=2 no vote
```

comment is a django model.

```
serializers.serialize('json', comment_with_vote, ensure_ascii=False)
```

returns AttributeError: 'CommentWithVote' object has no attribute '_meta'

```
json.dumps(comment_with_vote, ensure_ascii=False)
```

returns TypeError: <...CommentWithVote object at 0x046ED930> is not JSON serializable

Comment: You've asked 8 questions, and haven't accepted answers for any of them. I at least will not answer this one until you do.

Comment: I'm sorry that I was not familiar with stackoverflow 'style'. I have accepted all answers that I think helpful to me. Thank you for your reminds and the same to your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`serializers.serialize` is only for Django models, and your class isn't a model - it just contains a reference to one. And, unfortunately, `json.dumps` doesn't know about models or your container class.

I would approach this in a different way. Rather than having a separate CommentWithVote class, I would simply annotate the votes onto the standard Comment. The serializers still won't know about the vote attribute, as it's not a field, but you can do this: serialize to a standard Python dictionary, add the vote, then convert to JSON.

```
comment_list = serializers.serialize('python', comments)
for comment in comments:
    comment['fields']['vote'] = calculate_vote()
comment_json = json.dumps(comments)
```