# How to retain an added column in django queryset during serialization?

Tags: python, django

How do i retain my extra column i've added dynamically on a queryset during serialization to a json string?

this is my code:

```
tenant_unit = TenantUnit.objects.filter(unit__building__id=10)

# dynamically add a column unit_name
for tu in tenant_unit:
    tu.unit_name = tu.unit.unit_name

# at this point if i loop thru the queryset( tenant_unit)
# i can see my dynamic column - unit_name

# build a json string
json_data = serializers.serialize("json", tenant_unit)

# check what's inside the json string, "mising" unit_name
print json_data   # Can't find the unit_name ????
```

What's happening, and how can i go round this?

Gath

NB: Am doing this because serializers don't follow relationships inside a model, just returns your current model.

Comment: See my recent answer to an unrelated question which actually implements your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309600/what-is-the-way-to-serialize-a-user-defined-class/7330225#7330225

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more that the django serialiser looks at the columns, not at the attributes.

You can look at other serialisation tools: [wad of stuff serializer](http://code.google.com/p/wadofstuff/wiki/DjangoFullSerializers) springs to mind.

I wound up writing my own, that uses a django Form to serialise and deserialise.